Neural networks with uncertainties in training data
I have used Flax to train a neural network to fit a model to some data. All of the data points have a known uncertainty, as in each row has both a value and an uncertainty. (To be more explicit: the values are assumed to have some error drawn from a normal distribution with std sigma, and we have an estimate of sigma for each data point.) I have taken care of this for the output data by defining a custom loss function that calculates (target-predicted)^2/uncertainty^2. However, the input parameters have uncertainties as well. How can I account for their uncertainty?
